# Async Pipe used with Select/Options & ngModel/ngModelChange

Tags: angular

**Problem Description**

I am trying to make a `select`/`option`-based dropdown work with an observable fields using `asyncPipe` and `[ngModel]`/`(ngModelChange)`. Something is very wrong with my code because in run time the console outputs an `[object Object]` (please see image below).

What confuses me is that if I use `[value]="payPeriod.id"`, it works fine and the numeric `id` is successfully received on `setSelectedPayPeriod(...)` side.

**component.html**

```
  <select [ngModel]="selectedPayPeriod | json" (ngModelChange)="setSelectedPayPeriod($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let payPeriod of (payPeriodList | async)" [value]="payPeriod">{{ payPeriod.endDate }}</option>
  </select>
```

**component.ts**

```
get payPeriodList(): Observable<PayPeriod[]> {
  return this._contextService.payPeriodList;
}

get selectedPayPeriod(): Observable<PayPeriod> {
  return this._contextService.selectedPayPeriod;
}

setSelectedPayPeriod(newValue: PayPeriod): void {
  console.warn(newValue);
  this._contextService.setSelectedPayPeriod(newValue);
}
```

**Console output**

[image]

Comment: [value]="payPeriod" here payPeriod is an object. I do not think you can bind it directly to value. If you do so, it will use toString() by default.

Comment: @vannadream. You're right, but I was looking for a way to bind to a payPeriod object. So, the working solution for me was the one by AJT_82 -- the `[ngValue]="payPeriod"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`payPeriod` is an Object, so if you want to bind the whole object, use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`.

```
<option *ngFor="let payPeriod of (payPeriodList | async)" [ngValue]="payPeriod">{{ payPeriod.endDate }}</option>
```