# How to bind data from JSON response into Dropdown List Angular2?

Tags: json, forms, angular

I want to bind data that I received from my web server into my front end application however the data is showing up as undefined. The array itself is taking the number of objects available, and data is binding to the component but not the front end itself

Here is my Template:

form.component.html

```
    <label>Group ID</label>
      <div class="row" *ngIf="roles.length">
        <div class="col-md-4">
    <select [(ngModel)]="roles" name="group_id" class="form-control" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['group_id']" data-width='200px'>
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.id">  
    {{role.name}}
    </option>
    </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The data looks like this, I'm supposed to display the name based on the value

```
export class Group {
id: string;
name: string;
pwd_expiry_in_days: string;
}
```

My component looks like this, data is being received and I'm able to log the data perfectly within the component

```
  public roles: Array<Group> = [];
  currentGroup : Group;


   private getGroups() : Observable<any> {
    console.log("In Groups");
    let _url = "myURL";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('X-Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('X-AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(_url, options)
    .map(response => {
      var responseAsObject = response.json();
      console.log(responseAsObject); <--- Good response
      return responseAsObject;
    });
}


ngOnInit(){
  this.getGroups().subscribe(roles => { 
    this.roles = roles;
    console.log(this.roles); <--- Logs perfectly fine
  });
}
```

Now that I have **this.roles** containing my array of JSON objects to display to the front end, why is it failing to display them based on what I have in my template?

thank you!

Comment: Try using the async pipe in the for-loop `let role of roles|async`

Comment: Gives an error: ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Try to wrap your for loop with an `*ngIf=roles`. `<option *ngIf="roles" *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.id">  
    {{role.name}}
    </option>` or on the outer element `<select *ngIf="roles" ...... </select>` (without using the async pipe)

Comment: Also, have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089350/async-pipe-used-with-select-options-ngmodel-ngmodelchange. they use the async pipe on both the select element and the option-element loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public roles$: Observable<Array<Group>>;
currentGroup : Group;


private getGroups() : Observable<Group[]> {
    console.log("In Groups");
    let _url = "myURL";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('X-Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('X-AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(_url, options)
               .map(response => response.json());
}


ngOnInit(){
  this.roles$ = this.getGroups()
                    .do(console.log);
}
```

...

```
<label>Group ID</label>
<div class="row" *ngIf="(roles$ | async)?.length">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select [(ngModel)]="roles" name="group_id" class="form-control" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['group_id']" data-width='200px'>
        <option *ngFor="let role of ($roles | async)" [value]="role.ID">{{role.NAME}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Type 'Observable<Group[]>' is not assignable to type 'Group[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<Group[]>' - In OnInit

Comment: Are you sure, that you have changed type of roles$?

Comment: you were right, I fixed it however the drop down list is empty. Before it would display 2 undefined objects

Comment: Great, one step by another ;-) In your console.logs, id and name values are set, right? Is it possible to post the log?

Comment: Which step would you like to see the log? inside the response?

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Another thing, which could be a problem is the ngModel-directive

Comment: Having trouble logging the response the way it is now, how would I log it exactly? :/

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check the ngOnInit ;-) Can you also remove the ngModel temporary?

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.getGroups(...).do is not a function

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

Comment: Yes, but it's uppercase...Check my answer again :-)

Comment: What did you change? the do function worked and I got a good JSON response. I posted the console.log in my previous comment

Comment: Check the html. The binding now uses uppercase properties

Comment: modified it, the drop down is still empty (no binding)

Comment: Ok, last try before i give up. Have you already removed the ngModel-directive?

Comment: the naming convention to upper case worked because the data members were being retrieved in upper case from  the database. So the modification to fix it was to change my model to upper case as you suggested. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your console logs may show data after they've been received in an async function.
What you see in the console log most probably is called after. Please could you try :

```
return new Promise<any>((resolve,reject) =>{
   this.http.get(_url, options)
   .map(response => {
      var responseAsObject = response.json();
      resolve(responseAsObject);
    });
    .toPromise()
    .catch(error =>{
      reject(error);
    })
})

ngOnInit(){
  this.getGroups().then(roles => { 
    this.roles = roles;
    console.log(this.roles);
  });
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use Observables than Promises?

Comment: Yes, indeed observables have more functionality, but if you don't need that functionality I see no point in using one.